# Python open("file", "w+") not creating a nonexistent file

Tags: python, macos, file, file-io, with-statement

Similar questions exist on Stack Overflow. I have read such questions and they have not resolved my problem. The simple code below results in a File Not Found Error. I am running  Python 3.9.1 on Mac OS X 11.4

Can anyone suggest next steps for troubleshooting the cause of this?

```
with open("/Users/root/test/test.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write("test")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/root1/PycharmProjects/web_crawler/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    with open("/Users/root/test/test.txt", "w+") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/root/test/test.txt'
```

Comment: Try removing the first `/` infront of Users

Comment: does `Users/root/test/` directory exist? if not, that could be the problem so try creating that directory first before running this code.

Comment: Removing the leading '/' in front of 'Users' did not resolve the issue.  '/Users/root/' is a valid existing directory, but  'test/' does not exist. I am writing a web-crawler to download media into directories corresponding to the authors' name and require some method that can generate directories and files not already existing. Any advice? I know os.mkdir() can do this, but I thought w+ offered the same functionality?

Comment: Creating '/test/' before running this will allow it to run as expected, but using os.mkdir() seems like it shouldn't be necessary

Comment: Why do you assume that open will create a directory that doesn't exist? It's not documented to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You comments on initial post clarify what you need to happen.
Below assumes that

- The directory `Users/root1/` exists
- You are trying to create a new sub directory + file inside it

```
import os

# Wrap this in a loop if you need
new_dir = 'test' # The variable directory name
new_path = 'Users/root1/' + new_dir + "/"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(new_path), exist_ok=True) # Create new dir 'Users/root1/${new_dir}/

with open(new_path + "test.txt", "w+") as f:
    # Create new file in afore created directory
    f.write("test")
```

This creates a new directory based on a variable `new_dir` and creates the file `test.txt` in it.

Answer (score 0):

**sometimes the compiler can't find any path like that you insert in open() function. at that time as possible  you can save by default in the folder where your programs were saved by IDE. the followed syntax may be helpful for you **

```
with open('test.txt', 'w+') as f:
     f.write("xyz")
```

**here the text.txt will save default in the folder where your IDE stores the program that you write. you can check that folder for conformation **